# Why when I execute changes in other fields the selected elements of the CheckBox are deleted - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a set of CheckBoxes that work perfectly, but when making changes in another section within the same view they are cleaned and unmarked by themselves, why is this happening ?, I have not found anything on the web about that ...

This is how I generate the CheckBox:

```
Check box(
                  lbl: "Gloves",
                  variable: 'gloves',
                  callbackCheckBox: callbackCheckBox),
```

When I select the CheckBox I call a callback () to receive the selected object and know if it is true or false, like this:

```
  void callbackCheckBox (String variable, bool value) {
    setState (() {
      print ('callbackCheckBox: var = $ variable, value = $ value');
      if (variable == 'gloves' && value == true) gloves = true;
    });
  }
```

So far, everything is perfect, but when I execute this code, what is selected from the CheckBox is deleted:

```
void isVisibleSignatureC1 () {setState (() {_isVisibleSignatureC1 =! _isVisibleSignatureC1; if (! _ isVisibleSignatureC1) imageSignatureC1 = imageSignatureNetwork; else imageSignatureC1 = imageSignatureAssets;});}
```

I use this code to change the image that is displayed in a Container () and the same thing happens when I execute a validator () of a TexField, just as the selected fields of the CheckBox are deleted.

And this is my CheckBox class that I call to create it:

```
class LabeledCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  const LabeledCheckbox ({
    this.label,
    this.padding,
    this.value,
    this.onChanged,
  });

  final String label;
  end EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool value;
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  Build widget (BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell (
      onTap: () {
        onChanged (! value);
      },
      child: Padding (
        padding: padding,
        child: Row (
          children: <Widget> [
            Expand (
                child: AutoSizeText (
                  label,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: TextStyle (
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                      color: Colors.black),
                ),
            ),
            Check box(
              value: value,
              activeColor: Color (0xFFff0000),
              onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                onChanged (newValue);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CheckBox extends StatefulWidget {

  final String lbl;
  ending String variable;
  Function callbackCheckBox;

  Check box({
    Key key,
    @required this.lbl,
    @required this.variable,
    @required this.callbackCheckBox,
  });

  @override
  _CheckBox createState () => _CheckBox ();
}

class _CheckBox extends State <CheckBox> {
  bool _isSelected = false;

  @override
  Build widget (BuildContext context) {
    return LabeledCheckbox (
      label: widget.lbl,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric (horizontal: 20.0),
      value: _isSelected,
      onChanged: (bool newValue) {
        setState (() {
          _isSelected = newValue;
          widget.callbackCheckBox (widget.variable, _isSelected);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is where i call isVisibleSignatureC1():

```
containerSignaturePermit(String variableData, var image,
    var _isVisibleSignature) {
  return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 100.0,
      height: 60.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Color(0xFFe5e5e5),
      ),
      //child: Text("${index + 1}", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () =>
            setState(() {
              print('$variableData, isVisibleSignature: $_isVisibleSignature');
            if('$variableData' == 'capplicantsig1') isVisibleSignatureC1();
            }),
        child: Container(
          height: screenHeight,
          width: screenWidth,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: image,
        ),
      )
  );
}
```

Anyone know why it happens and how to fix it to leave the fields checked and not cleared when making other changes in the same view.

Comment: that void isVisibleSignatureC1 is called in CheckBox() or in some parent widget? maybe the value _isSelected is reset to false if thats the case

Comment: I thought the same thing, but they don't share variables: /

Comment: can you add the code of the parent widget where you call isVisibleSignatureC1 or where the logic resets the checkbox?

Comment: There I uploaded the code where I call isVisibleSignatureC1 (), the strange thing is that it does not give me an error at any time ... The document I have in the view is very large, I thought that perhaps where I stop seeing the checkboxes on the screen, these are unchecked by doing setState () on other objects that are much lower, such as a TextField or something like that.

Comment: oh are you using a scroll? does this happen when its aut of the screen only? if thats the case maybe you need to use the mixin AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin in the state of your class CheckBox

Comment: Yes I am using a scroll view. When I mark the Checkboxes and the TextFields and see both, neither is lost, but if I mark the CheckBoxes, then I scroll and stop seeing the CheckBoxes or the TextFields and change other Widgets with setState () that are below, it eliminates the changes I had made on top that are no longer visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you told me your CheckBox class lose the state after scrolling away and setState so maybe what you need is to use [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) in the CheckBox class so even if it's out of the screen when you get back the value is preserved

```
class CheckBox extends StatefulWidget { //This is the same

  final String lbl;
  ending String variable;
  Function callbackCheckBox;

  Check box({
    Key key,
    @required this.lbl,
    @required this.variable,
    @required this.callbackCheckBox,
  });

  @override
  _CheckBox createState () => _CheckBox ();
}

class _CheckBox extends State<CheckBox> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<CheckBox> { //Add the mixin to the state
  bool _isSelected = false;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; //this tells the state to keep it alive

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(); // call this at the beginning of the build method, it's to save the state in the mixin
    return LabeledCheckbox (
      label: widget.lbl,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric (horizontal: 20.0),
      value: _isSelected,
      onChanged: (bool newValue) {
        setState (() {
          _isSelected = newValue;
          widget.callbackCheckBox (widget.variable, _isSelected);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You saved my life, I did not understand why it happened. I figured it was because widgets that were not seen were destroyed, but I didn't know how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: yeah some scrolls build their wiget lazily, that means it destroys the one outside the screen to save memory (imaging saving a cache list with 1000 images), this prevents to destroy the states of the widgets that matter